Popening a gnome-terminal in python immediately appears as a zombie
For background I am working on a script to train multiple pytorch models. I have a training script that I want to be able to run as a sub process in a gnome terminal. The main reason for this is so I can keep an eye on the training progress. In cases where I might have multiple GPUs I would like to run my training script multiple times in separate windows. To accomplish this I have been using popen. The following code works to open a new terminal window and start the training script
#create a list of commands
commands = []
kd_cfg = KDConfig.read(kd_cfg_path)
cmd = "python scripts/train_torch.py "
for specialist in kd_cfg.specialists:
    cmd += f"--config {kd_cfg.runtime_dict['specialists'][specialist]['config']} "
    ...

# Run each command in a new terminal and store the process object
num_gpus = len(gpus)
free_gpus = copy.deepcopy(gpus)
processes = []
worker_sema = threading.Semaphore(num_gpus)
commands_done = [False for _ in range(len(commands))]

#start the watchdog
watch = threading.Thread(target=watch_dog, args=(processes,free_gpus,commands_done,worker_sema))
watch.start()

for cmd_idx, command in enumerate(commands):

    worker_sema.acquire()

    gpu = free_gpus.pop()
    command += f" --gpu {gpu}" #allocate a free GPU from the list
    split_cmd_arr = shlex.split(command)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--'] + split_cmd_arr)

    processes.append( (cmd_idx,gpu,proc) )


The part that I am stuck on is the concurrency control. In order to protect the GPU resource I use a semaphore. My plan was to monitor the process that starts the GNOME terminal and when it has finished release the semaphore to start the next training process. Instead what happens is that all commands are run at the same time. When I test with two commands and limit onto one gpu I still see two terminals open and two trainings will begin. In my watchdog thread code below I see that both the processes are zombies and have no children even WHILE I am watching the training loop execute inside of both terminals without crashing.
   # Check if processes are still running
    while not all(commands_done):
        for cmd_idx, gpu, proc in processes:
            # try:
            # Check if process is still running
            ps_proc = psutil.Process(proc.pid)

            #BC we call bash python out of the gate it executes as a child proc
            ps_proc_children = get_child_processes(proc.pid)
            proc_has_running_children = any(child.is_running for child in ps_proc_children)

            print(f"status: {ps_proc.status()}")
            print(f"children:  {ps_proc_children}")
            if proc_has_running_children:
                print(f"Process {proc.pid} on GPU {gpu} is still running", end='\r')
            else:
                print(f"Process {proc.pid} has terminated")
                free_gpus.append(gpu)
                commands_done[cmd_idx] = True
                processes.remove((cmd_idx, gpu, proc))

                ps_proc.wait()
                print(f"removed proc {ps_proc.pid}")
                worker_sema.release()

I thought maybe the subprocess basically starts another process then immediately returns but I am surprised to see that there are no children either. If anyone has any insights they would be much apprecaited.
If it helps this is some example output from the watchdog.
status: zombie
children:  []
Process 4076 has terminated
removed proc 4076
status: zombie
children:  []
Process 4133 has terminated
removed proc 4133


/////////////////////EDIT/////////////////////////////////
I still have yet to find a way directly get the PID of the processes through the POPEN interface. I have a workaround but I still think there should be a cleaner way to do this.
What I have done is make use of the ps_util process_iter function. I iterate all of the running processes and look at the commands and do a regex match to find a matching command. There are enough uniqueish things like the GPU number and a date time string that are getting passed that its unlikely two things would match [but that is a major drawback to the approach]
def get_pid_for_unique_cmd(cmdl_string2find):

    pid = None
    for pp in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'cmdline']):

        cmdl_cmd = ""
        if pp.info["cmdline"]:
            cmdl_cmd = ' '.join(pp.info['cmdline'])


        #if there is not single space in the typed command it gets mad so need to strip
        if "".join(cmdl_cmd.split()) == "".join(cmdl_string2find.split()):

            pid = pp.pid
            print(f"found process {pid} that matches {cmdl_string2find}")
            print(pp.info)
            ps_proc = psutil.Process(pid)
            print(f"status {ps_proc.status()}")
            print()

    return pid

Im then passing that pid the watchdog thread, where I updated things to check for that pid instead of using the proc object.

I think what happens is that, in your watchdog thread, you're modifying the list processes while iterating over it. This doesn't reliably remove elements from the list. As a result, your watchdog thread checks the state of the same process multiple times and releases the semaphore too many times.
Try, replacing for cmd_idx, gpu, proc in processes
with
for cmd_idx, gpu, proc in processes.copy().
(You could also do it by iterating over indexes in the list but you'd have to keep track of how many elements you have deleted)

IIRC removing elements from a list using .remove will work fine, but the iterator will skip elements.

@nneonnea: yes that's what I meant, the iterator will skip elements, so in that watchdog thread, some of the triplets that should get deleted don't get deleted. The .remove method will work fine but it won't get a chance to get called on some of the elements that should get removed.

Thanks for the response, while I agree this might cause problems it doesn't seem to make a difference if I iterate processes vs processes[:]. I'm more so looking to cleanly monitor the processes running the gnome terminals that I started with POPEN.
